# stream wrapper and writing to php://memory results in internal server error 500

Tags: php, linux, stream-wrapper, php-stream-wrappers

I'm trying to write a custom wrapper in PHP using the [Stream Wrapper](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.streamwrapper.php) class. What I have now is pretty much simple and straight forward.

```
class Stream
{
    public $resource;

    public static function wrap()
    {
        stream_wrapper_unregister(self::PROTOCOL);
        stream_wrapper_register(self::PROTOCOL, __CLASS__);
    }

    public static function unwrap ( )
    {
        stream_wrapper_restore(self::PROTOCOL);
    }

    public function stream_open ( $path, $mode, $options, &$openedPath )
    {
        $this->unwrap();

        // Open memory
        $this->resource = fopen('php://memory', 'rb+');
        $code = file_get_contents ( $path );

        // Write code to memory
        fwrite($this->resource, $code);
        rewind($this->resource);

        $this->wrap();

        return $this->resource !== false;
    }

    // Left out the other methods that the stream wrapper needs 
    // to keep this example simple
    // ...
}
```

In the beginning of my code I open the stream by calling: `Stream::wrap()`.

Then it basically reads any file that is `require`'ed or `include`'ed throughout my application. The code is then put into `php://memory` and that's it. Nothing special yet.

Bottom line is, is that this piece of code should work. But it throws an **Internal Server Error** when I try to run my application. I have a Linux hosting provider (PHP 5.4.21) where my code is currently hosted.

But when I move my code from my current hoster to some other Linux hosting company (PHP 5.5.x), then everything works fine.

When I even move the code to my local computer (PHP 5.4.6) and run it, then everything works fine as well.

So obviously the problem lies at the hosting company that I currently have. I know I have to mail them. But I have no clue what is causing the problem exactly. It would be good if I could at least point them in a certain direction. All I have now is

> my code isn't working on your servers which is working fine on some
>   other server

I'm afraind that that isn't enough information for them.

I have checked the `php://memory` limit which is set to 256M. That should be more than enough. So I have no clue what else to look for. The Apache log didn't had any information either.

So I was hoping anyone here had an idea of what could be causing this problem. Perhaps some permission issue somewhere or something?

Comment: Check the web server error logs to see what php's problem is. The 500 error is sent from the web server, not php.

Comment: @JonathanKuhn The web server logs are the Apache logs right? That's why i said that i checked those already :) The error logs seem to be empty. So I'll have to contact my host anyway because no errors in it at all seem strange.